# Sony Xperia L device memory is being eaten up

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

My phone's /data storage is getting fuller all by itself even though I have not installed much apps. By doing some search on net have found that there are folders under Data folder such as tombstones, thumbnails etc. which are taking up the space but which are not accessible without rooting. I want to clear up this space without rooting the device.

My device is a Sony Xperia L running Android 4.1.3 Jelly Bean)

Answer (score 1):

It needn't necessarily be tombstones and thumbnails that takes up your phone's data storage.

Normal app usage (mostly browser cache, etc.) also consumes space over time.

Have a look at

```
Settings->App->All apps
```

then via menu let them **Sort by size** to see the biggest storage consumers.

E.g. my phone's biggest consumer is Chrome (123MB data, 280MB cache):

[image].

Comment: have done all these things ...that is not the issue..i have done factory reset more  than 5 times but this issue does not get resolved..

Answer (score 0):

Free up space on the internal SD card folder.

With Jelly Bean the formerly separate SDcard data is also stored on /data (/data/media to be precise). Free up some space there, it counts to the overall sum on /data.

Reason: /data and the *external storage* partition have been merged to only have *one* partition and benefit from a single storage scales better. It removes the need to choose a reasonable hard partition size split for /data and /sdcard as before. For compatibility reasons, the /data/media folder is exposed via a virtual fuse layer that emulates the former FAT properties and hides the internal structure from apps. Android Police has an interview why this was done [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/18/impromptu-qa-session-with-android-engineer-dan-morrill-brings-to-light-reasons-behind-galaxy-nexus-lack-of-usb-mass-storage/).